# Proximity sensor stuck in one position

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, lg, proximity-sensor

I have noticed that sometimes screen doesn't go black during call as it should, and also double tap to wake sometimes doesn't​ react. So I opened AIDA64, and under sensors/proximity sensors it shows 1 or 0 when sensor work fine but when it doesn't turn off screen sensor is "locked" to 1 or 0. After reboot sensor is going back to normal. Is there any way to find out who is to blame for locking sensor in one state?
The device is LG K8 (k350nds) running stock Android marshmallow 6.0, non-rooted.

Comment: What device, Android version, and is it stock or custom ROM? I have seen some devices that the sensor can be calibrated, but getting "stuck" is unusual... this is often caused by screen protector (or smudges/dirt on it) or a case that slightly overlaps the sensor's detection field.

Comment: @acejavelin Added info in question. Well I don't have any screen protector or dirt there. However in that case sensor would return 0 value like when it's hovered​, not sometimes 1 and sometimes 0.

Comment: Hmmm... A common LG issue, try sensor re-calibration. To recalibrate the sensor, dial *#546368#*350# when you are presented with the options, go to Device Test and choose SAAT. Then tap on Service Menu Manual Test and then tap on Key and next tap on Test then Cal Start. This will help you recalibrate the proximity sensors. Use your phone after the recalibration to check if it works properly.

Comment: @acejavelin After I tap on Cal start nothing happens, I ended the test and tried calling but screen still doesn't go off during call.

Comment: And  what if the sensor was defective?

Comment: @esQmo_ I doubt it, because it works fine after reboot. I'm tired of rebooting..